# env: bash: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, nginx, passenger

(Yes I have checked other answers, and this has nothing to do with line endings.)

I am getting the following subprocess error deploying `Passenger` on `nginx`.  This is on `FreeBSD-11.1`:

```
env: bash: No such file or directory
```

Very strange.  The `nginx` process starts up as `root`, then moves to `nobody`, whose shell I have indeed changed to `/usr/local/bin/bash`.  How either of these users can't see `bash` is strange.  But their reported paths don't include `/usr/local/bin`:

The `root` environment:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),5(operator)

SERVER_SOFTWARE=nginx/1.14.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.3.4
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD=true
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
PWD=/
HOME=/
RC_PID=1360
```

And for `nobody`:

```
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nobody) groups=65534(nobody)

PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
PASSENGER_SPAWN_WORK_DIR=/tmp/passenger.spawn.lJk10nqveb
RC_PID=1360
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD=true
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5/gems/passenger/src/nodejs_supportlib
NODE_ENV=production
USER=nobody
PWD=/usr/local/www/pneb
HOME=/nonexistent
PASSENGER_APP_ENV=production
RAILS_ENV=production
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash
RACK_ENV=production
SHLVL=0
IN_PASSENGER=1
WSGI_ENV=production
LOGNAME=nobody
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
SERVER_SOFTWARE=nginx/1.14.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.3.4
```

Neither of these users can see bash.  I'm not sure which is throwing the error.

How can I get past this issue?  I expect `Passenger` working with `nginx` to be able to see shells.

Comment: Your `PATH` does not contain `/usr/local/bin`, as you already wrote, so it will not be able to find it. Either append `:/usr/local/bin` to `PATH`, or use the full path to start `bash`.

Comment: That's the problem.  The `nobody` user has no home, no bash_profile.  So it cannot be done.

Comment: Somewhere on your system is the configuration that starts nginx. You can change the PATH there. Where "there" is depends on details you have told us nothing about -- is nginx running as a systemd service? Under upstart? SysV inittab? ...?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so `nginx.conf` should have `$PATH` insertions?  The only thing I know to control in there is the user, which is set to `www`.  I believe it's a `systemd` service.  It's always running.

Comment: No, not nginx.conf -- that's read *after* nginx is started. We want to configure the thing on your system that starts nginx.

Comment: ...what exactly that "thing on your system" is, again, depends on details you aren't telling us. Which OS are you running? With which process supervision system? Are you using a 3rd-party package for nginx, or one you built yourself? Or is this in a Docker container? etc.

Comment: I'm not sure.  It's always running.  Installed and set in `/etc/rc.conf`.  `nginx_enable="yes"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178874/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-rich-f).

Answer (score 3):

Solved, thanks to Charles Duffy in chat:

Add the following to the `nginx` launcher at `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/nginx`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

This gives nginx a `PATH` to see `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. This solve my problem by running this in the .zsh terminal

Open .zshrc by running $ nano .zshrc
then
Added this to the file:
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$PATH